# Remove ToastNotification from ActionCenter

Tags: c#, windows-10, desktop-application, toast

I have a desktop application running in Windows 10 which creates ToastNotifications that are also being stored in the Action Center. I noticed, that when I reboot the computer the Notifications are still present in the Action Center so I wanted to remove them through my Application when they're not necessary anymore.
I wanted to use the [ToastNotificationHistory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationhistory) `Remove` method for this.
My code looks like this:

```
public static void RemoveNotificationByTag(string toastTag)
{
    ToastNotificationManager.History.Remove(toastTag, "TEST");
}
```

But this leads to this exception: `System.Exception: 'Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)'`

The notification I've been sending priorly has a `Tag` and a `Group` value.

I get the same exception when calling the `RemoveGroup` or `GetHistory` method. Basically it seems like I cannot call any method from the History class without getting the same exception

Comment: just a suggestion. Try printing all the items in "ToastNotificationManager.History" and check if it contains the toast you need.

Comment: Why not just call `Clear()`? _"Removes all notifications sent by this app from action center."_

Comment: I tried to have a look at the History object in the debugger but that just shows: To inspect the native object, enable native code debugging. As soon as I enable it, it says Operation not supported. Calling the Clear method leads to the same exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows 10 it is necessary to provide the applicationId parameter to each of the methods. Also you must specify not only a toast tag, but its group as well.

Calling the method like this works:

```
ToastNotificationManager.History.Remove(toastTag, "TEST", appId);
```